# How to parse list of Json Objects using Retrofit Api

Tags: android, json, retrofit

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
        "img": "ginterests/1.png",
        "title": "Training & Educations",
        "description": "Yoga | Fitness | Daily Trainings | Dance | Music +",
        "follow": 1
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2",
        "img": "ginterests/2.png",
        "title": "Consultations",
        "description": "Legal | Studies | Entrance Exam Preparations +",
        "follow": 1
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "3",
        "img": "ginterests/3.png",
        "title": "Public Events",
        "description": "City Events | Trending | Current Events +",
        "follow": 0
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "4",
        "img": "ginterests/4.png",
        "title": "Business Events",
        "description": "Talks & Shows | Press | Live coverage | Business meets +",
        "follow": 0
    },
    "4": {
        "id": "5",
        "img": "ginterests/5.png",
        "title": "Performances",
        "description": "Regional & Global | Celebreties | Standup +",
        "follow": 0
    },
    "5": {
        "id": "6",
        "img": "ginterests/6.png",
        "title": "News & Entertainment",
        "description": "Regional & Global | News | Trending +",
        "follow": 0
    },
    "6": {
        "id": "7",
        "img": "ginterests/default.png",
        "title": "Celebrities",
        "description": "City Events | Trending | Current Events +",
        "follow": 0
    },
    "success": true,
    "message": "Interests data sent",
    "interestsCount": 7
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what and how you want to archieve and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Since there is no unified structure of this object, there is no easy way without an object for fields 0-6... Not clear what you've tried, though

Comment: If at all possible, I would suggest you make `ginterests` an array rather than numbered JSON keys

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSON object and getting the individual data from it is easy. Just follow the below steps:

1. Store the complete response as a string value:`final String response= response.body().string();`
2. Initialize a JSON object:`JSONObject resultObject = null;`
3. Now run the below code to parse the data from your JSON object: `try {

   ```
               resultObject = new JSONObject(response);
               JSONObject result = resultObject.getJSONObject(0);
               final String id= volumeObject.getString("id"); //repeat this step to get all the data from the JSON object 
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }`
   ```